# Orthogonal FS become weak FS if you switch classes

Tags: ct.category-theory

I've always been surprised by the fact that $(Epi, Mono)$ is, when possible, a [strong factorization system](http://ncatlab.org/joyalscatlab/published/Factorisation+systems) (unique solution to lifting problems, existence of unique factorization), whereas $(Mono, Epi)$ is only a [*weak* factorization system](http://ncatlab.org/joyalscatlab/published/Weak+factorisation+systems). How can one tell when something similar happen in general? Is there any other known example of such a situation?

PS: I know that orthogonality (which is the thing I'm focused on in my question) is not enough to define a factorization system, weak or not. If you think the question is more amenable replacing factorizations with *pre*factorizations, feel free to consider the problem of determining when $\mathcal E\perp \mathcal M$ (strong) and $\mathcal M\pitchfork\mathcal E $ (weak).

Comment: Please would you say what you mean by strong and weak. I am not sure that I have heard such terminology before for factorisation systems.  Besides, these words are grossly over-used in mathematics.

Comment: I added links to the Joyal catlab with the definitions.