# Interlocking (weak) factorization systems

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

I'm interested in instances of the following data:

- $C$ is a (possibly higher) category;
- $(L,M)$ is a [weak factorization system (wfs)](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+factorization+system) on $C$;
- $(M,R)$ is a [unique factorization system (fs)](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orthogonal+factorization+system) on $C$.

**Definition:** I'll call such data $(L,M,R)$ *interlocking factorization systems on $C$* because the right half of the wfs coincides with the left half of the fs.

**Examples:**

- On the 1-category $Set$ we have the $(Mono,Epi)$ wfs and the $(Epi,Mono)$ fs.
- On the $\infty$-category $Spaces$ we have (as discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352803/what-do-you-call-a-map-of-spaces-which-is-weakly-left-orthogonal-to-all-n-conn)) the $((n+1)\text{-skel_r}, n\text{-conn})$ wfs and the $(n\text{-conn},n\text{-trunc})$ fs [1], for any $n \in \mathbb Z_{\geq -2}$.
- On the 1-category $Ch_{\geq 0}(R\text{-Mod})$, we have the $(\text{acyclic mono with projective cokernel}, \text{epi})$ wfs and the $(\text{epi}, \text{mono})$ fs, for any ring $R$.

**Question 1:** What are some other examples of the above data of "interlocking factorization systems"?

**Observations:**

- If $(L,M,R)$ forms interlocking factorization systems on $C$, then $(M,R)$ is a [modality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modality) (i.e. a fs with basechange-stable left class). Moreover, $M$ is closed under co-transfinite-composition. In fact, we might think of $(L,M,R)$ as being fundamentally a fs $(M,R)$ where $M$ satsifies some further closure conditions like these (though it's [not clear](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352830/characterizing-the-left-right-classes-of-weak-factorization-systems-in-local) that there's actually an *equivalent* formulation along these lines).
- Dually, we might think of an interlocking factorization system $(L,M,R)$ on $C$ as being fundamentally a wfs $(L,M)$ where $M$ satisfies some further closure conditions (namely, cobase-change and colimits in the arrow category). If $C$ is locally presentable, then modulo checking that $M$ is accessibly embedded, this is actually an equivalent formulation.

**Question 2:** Given a class of morphisms $M$ in a ($\infty$-)category $C$ (perhaps assumed to be locally presentable),

- does knowing that $M$ is the left half of a fs $(M,R)$ in any way "simplify" the task of checking whether $M$ is the right half of a wfs $(L,M)$?
- dually, does knowing that $M$ is the right half of a wfs $(L,M)$ imply anything interesting about whether $M$ is also the left half of a fs $(M,R)$?

**Question 3:** Are interlocking factorization systems just a curiosity, or is there anything special you can do with them? For instance, do they lead to some kind of obstruction theory?

[1] Here,

- $(n+1)\text{-skel_r}$ denotes the retracts of relative $(n+1)$-dimensional CW complexes
- $n\text{-conn}$ denotes the $n$-connected maps (= maps with $n$-connected fibers, off by 1 from the most classical convention)
- $n\text{-trunc}$ denotes the $n$-truncated maps (= maps with $n$-truncated fibers, which again may be off by 1 from your favorite convention)

Comment: One example worth understanding could be the following: it is known that t-structures on the homotopy category of a given $(\infty,1)$-category are in bijection with a suitable class of factorization systems (called normal torsion theories). It could be interesting to study which $t$-structures correspond to "normal interlocking torsion theories"... e.g., are they the TTFs studied in the PhD thesis of Pedro Nicolas (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.0507.pdf) or do we need to impose some more conditions to get a bijection?

Comment: This isn't quite the same phenomenon, but [ternary factorisation systems](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ternary+factorization+system) share similar structure in being overlapping factorisation systems in some sense, though they're stronger than the notion you're interested in (at least when $R_1 = L_2$).

Comment: Long ago I asked what's up with those FS such that $(E,M)$ is a OFS and $(M,E)$ a WFS; this doesn't seem to be understood. (I would call these particular interlocking FS _Frobenius_, for obvious reasons). Fiorenza, Marchetti and I studied the notion of "stable n-ary OFS" to describe Postnikov towers in https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04658: not that this was really unknown. It just come out better when done $\infty$. Hopefully you can adapt that technology?

Comment: @Fosco Thanks! I just came across [this question of yours](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/183054/orthogonal-fs-become-weak-fs-if-you-switch-classes) related to the first question above, as well as [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184506/llpepi-epi-is-a-wfs-on-any-variety-of-algebras) which yields, following Joyal's Catlab, a class of examples generalizing the first and third above. Namely, if $C$ is any variety of algebras, then $({}^\square Surj, Surj, Inj)$ is an interlocking factorization system on $C$. Awesome!

Comment: I suppose another class of examples would be the following. Let $C^{op}$ be a Grothendieck topos or a Grothendieck abelian category. Then the triple $((Mono^\square)^{op},Mono^{op},Epi^{op})$ is an interlocking factorization system on $C$.

Comment: Tim Campion. Your last observation can be extended. Dual of an interlocking factorization system is $(R,M,L)$ where $(R,M)$ is a factorization system and $(M,L)$ is a weak factorization system. I met this situation in my arXiv:1702.08684 paper. Examples are on Boolean algebras, Banach spaces, or commutative $C^\ast$-algebras. The last example yields an interlocking factorization system on compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Trivial observation about question 2: at least it's automatically closed under retracts... (-:O

Comment: @MikeShulman: It contains the isomorphisms and is closed under composition, too :)