# Relations between the operations of taking weak orthogonals

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories

While reading the Hovey Model Category I learned that $I^{rlr} = I^r$ and $I^{lrl} = I^l$ for every class of morphisms $I$. What other relations are there between the operations of taking (weak) orthogonals? Are all $I^l, I^{ll}, I^{lll}, I^{llll}, ..$ distinct in general?

Comment: In general no: in any category $C$, for $I$ the class of its isomorphisms, $I^l=\hom(C)$ (all morphisms of $C$), and $\hom(C)^l=I$, so you have an "oscillating" sequence.

Comment: Another potential source of counterexample is $Set$: in the category of sets (with choice and all you need to make this true) $Epi=Mono^{l!}$ (strong orthogonality) but also $Epi=Mono^r$ (because $(Epi,Mono)$ is an orthogonal FS on $Set$, but $(Mono,Epi)$ is a weak one), so $Epi^l=Mono^{rl}=Mono$; now $Epi^{ll}=Mono^l$ which I would try to show is just $Epi=Mono^{l!}$, despite the stronger orthogonality request.

Comment: Hmm, I use "in general" in the opposite sense. I mean "are there any relations true for every class I", "what are the equalities we are sure of, regardless of information about the class of morphisms".

Comment: @fosco Note that if $M$ is a class of monomorphisms in a 1-category, then $M^{l} = M^{l!}$ always, so it's not necessary to distinguish between weak and strong orthogonality in this particular case. So we do indeed have $Epi = Mone^l$ in $Set$, and get another oscillating sequence as you suggested!

Comment: I would suggest that typically it's not very natural to consider the operations $(-)^{ll}$ or $(-)^{rr}$. Let $\mathcal L = \mathcal R = \{\text{classes of morphsisms in }\mathcal C\}$, ordered by inclusion. Then $(-)^l : \mathcal R^{op} {}^\to_\leftarrow : \mathcal R (-)^r$ is an adjunction, with interesting fixed points. But I think of it as "an accident" that $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal R$ are the same set. That being said, I wouldn't rule out that this perspective might be misleading -- maybe there are interesting things to say here!

Comment: A [couple](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369270/interlocking-weak-factorization-systems) of [related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313661/sequences-of-iterated-orthogonals-lifting-property-in-a-category?rq=1) [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397550/when-is-a-right-lifting-property-closed-under-pushouts/398101#398101).

Comment: In $R$-mod a module $M$ is injective iff $M\to 0$ is in $\{ R \to 0 \}^{rr}$, which is an example of $(-)^{rr}$.